# Getting all documents from MongoDB instead of all Models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm calling MongoDB from my Node app using Mongoose like this:

```
var query = itemModel.find();
query.exec(function (err, items) {
  console.log(err);
  socket.emit("items", items); 
});
```

I have 3 models defined like this:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var playerModel = require('./models/player.js').make(Schema, mongoose);
var characterModel = require('./models/character.js').make(Schema, mongoose, ObjectId);
var itemModel = require('./models/item.js').make(Schema, mongoose);
```

my models look like this:

```
function make(Schema, mongoose) {
    itemSchema = new Schema({
        name: String
      , bonus: [{ 
            type: String
          , value: Number 
        }]
      , price: Number
      , slot: String
    });
    return mongoose.model('Character', characterSchema);
}
exports.make = make;
```

For some reason I'm getting all documents, regardless of them being items, characters or players. Since I'm calling find() on itemModel I was expecting only Items, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your "my models look like" code doesn't look right.  You're creating `itemSchema` and then referencing `characterSchema` in the `mongoose.model` call.  Is that just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model that you have shown appears to be the item model, but you are creating the model with the 'Character' name. This means that you told Mongoose about the scheme for an item and that it is stored in the 'character' collection. Assuming you've done the same for each other model (Character/Player), you've been Mongoose that everything is in the same collection.

Then you query that collection and you seem surprised that everything is stored in the same collection. It strikes me as if you have little experience with Mongoose/MongoDB, so I will suggest you download and learn to love MongoVUE. This application is a good GUI to see what is going on under the hood of the MongoDB database. While developing, you also might want to enable debugging so you can see what queries mongoose is launching to the server (mongoose.set('debug', true)).

Comment: Argh. The doom of copy/paste. Been banging my head for hours. Thanks and +1 for mongoVUC, that will be helpful